# MIPS, the Android Market, 3.0 SDK and JNI

Tags: android

Not a bits, bytes, algorithm and syntax question... but a technology development and business one.  Hope that's ok.

At CES 2011, mips.com unveiled new MIPS-processor based smart phones running Android.  By what I've read, it sounds like these either might be Chinese-market only (which, lets face it... is huge) or part of a big push by MIPS to elbow into ARM's territory.

Here are problems I see:
- Google only provide first-class support for ARM.  Their SDKs are ARM-only.  Does anyone know if they have plans to adopt MIPS?
- The Android Market is ARM-only, as far as I can tell.  It looks like companies like Velocity Micro (and their little MIPS-based Cruz tablet) have their own "Cruz Market".  I think that's awful.  Is the Android Market going to be the one-stop shop for Android, or are things fragmenting even more?
- The JNI breaks the processor-independence of the VM.  Can multiple processor-specific JNI libraries be packaged into a single app?  MIPS binaries aren't exactly small.

Does anyone out there have a crystal ball on these things?  Let the assumption be: MIPS won't just go away.

TL;DR: Anyone know WTF is going on with MIPS?

Comment: Sorry, but this is definitely an offtopic here. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Their SDKs are ARM-only.

The Android SDK is processor-agnostic, outside of emulator images.

> Does anyone know if they have plans to adopt MIPS?

The verb "adopt" is too nebulous for anyone to answer this question.

> The Android Market is ARM-only, as far as I can tell.

I am not aware of a non-ARM device that meets the Android Market compatibility requirements. This is not a chipset thing, it's a compatibility thing. For example, at present, all Android Market-compliant devices must have a touchscreen, which eliminates MIPS-powered set-top boxes.

> Can multiple processor-specific JNI libraries be packaged into a single app?

Yes. That is a key feature of the NDK.

Comment: Hi - and thanks for the reply.  The NDK is certainly ARM-only, as is the emulator, so by "adopt" I'd think it's pretty clear I mean: provide first-class support, i.e. provide the NDK and emulator with MIPS support.  MIPS tablets have touch screens, and of course the phones will too.  Thanks for the multi-library JNI note... didn't know this.  Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: @PaulM: "The NDK is certainly ARM-only" -- except that you referred to the Android SDK. "provide first-class support, i.e. provide the NDK and emulator with MIPS support" -- the NDK and tools initiatives are fully open source, developed in the public eye, so you are welcome to contribute your time and energy to add MIPS support. Beyond that, Google rarely announces "plans". The only other MIPS stuff I have encountered is discussions on adding the MIPS toolchain to the AOSP firmware and build process, which is being discussed on a relevant Google Group.

Comment: Link to the discussion mentioned: http://groups.google.com/group/android-contrib/browse_thread/thread/b0b076961ebd75fb#